# laravel 5 routing controller to different directory

Tags: laravel-5

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('call-plan', 'CustomerCallPlanController');
```

**Class**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Customer;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Html;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerCallPlanController extends CustomerBaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        dd('SUCCESS!');
    }
```

And I expect to see 'SUCCESS' message in blank page but I see this instead:

```
 ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
    Class App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController does not exist
    in Container.php line 741
    at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController') in Container.php line 741
    at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController', array()) in Container.php line 631
    at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController', array()) in Application.php line 674
    at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 85
    at ControllerDispatcher->makeController('App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 57
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController', 'index') in Route.php line 203
```

I see the message in exception tell *App\Http\Controllers\CustomerCallPlanController* it makes sense because my controller in Customer folder which means it should be *App\Http\Controllers\Customer\CustomerCallPlanController*
How can I fix this

Comment: CustomerCallPlanController is diferrent from CustomerQueueController.
Looks like a typo

Comment: Yeah its but I was edited here is the original..(same error)

Comment: Is it because your controller is in `Customer` but the route doesn't denote that?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes completely true

Comment: So you'll need to do something like this I assume, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative path:

```
Route::resource('call-plan', 'Customer\CustomerCallPlanController');
```

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers) under *Controllers & Namespaces*